Issue in run a flutter project with a android emulator
Launching lib\main.dart on AOSP on IA Emulator in debug mode...
FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

* What went wrong:
Could not open cp_settings generic class cache for settings file 'C:\Users\Faishana\Flutter_projects\healthcare_app\android\settings.gradle' (C:\Users\Faishana\.gradle\caches\8.0\scripts\a1w3xsedh8nmfinmqjxhisyir).
> BUG! exception in phase 'semantic analysis' in source unit '_BuildScript_' Unsupported class file major version 65

* Try:
> Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace.
> Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output.
> Run with --scan to get full insights.

* Get more help at https://help.gradle.org

BUILD FAILED in 1s

┌─ Flutter Fix ────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────┐
│ [!] Your project's Gradle version is incompatible with the Java version that Flutter is using    │
│ for Gradle.                                                                                      │
│                                                                                                  │
│ If you recently upgraded Android Studio, consult the migration guide at                          │
│ https://flutter.dev/to/to/java-gradle-incompatibility.                                           │
│                                                                                                  │
│ Otherwise, to fix this issue, first, check the Java version used by Flutter by running `flutter  │
│ doctor --verbose`.                                                                               │
│                                                                                                  │
│ Then, update the Gradle version specified in                                                     │
│ C:\Users\Faishana\Flutter_projects\healthcare_app\android\gradle\wrapper\gradle-wrapper.properti │
│ es to be compatible with that Java version. See the link below for more information on           │
│ compatible Java/Gradle versions:                                                                 │
│ https://docs.gradle.org/current/userguide/compatibility.html#java                                │
│                                                                                                  │
│                                                                                                  │
└──────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────┘
Error: Gradle task assembleDebug failed with exit code 1

Exited (1).

what is this issue?
How to solve?
I try with chatgpt but it was not work

If you can produce a minimal example (MCVE) and share it via github or other public code sharing site that would help. The main thing I notice is this link is given, suggest you read that:
https://docs.flutter.dev/release/breaking-changes/android-java-gradle-migration-guide
The error mentions "class file major version 65" which is Java 21, see https://javaalmanac.io/bytecode/versions/ .
Make sure you are using a recent version of Android Studio and that you are using the latest gradle version and latest AGP version. See https://developer.android.com/build/releases/gradle-plugin#updating-plugin . Also check https://developer.android.com/build/jdks for Java version related issues.
I don't know much about flutter but Android itself might have trouble with Java 21 class files depending on the use of modern APIs since most Android devices barely support Java 11 as it is.
